# Trigonometric Property

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

How can I show that the following property holds?

$2\cos(4a)+2\cos(2a)+1=\displaystyle\frac{\sin(5a)}{\sin(a)}$

I've been trying to derive it to no avail. What would be a way to approach similar problems like this? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Using 
$$\sin(A+B)=\sin (A)\cos (B)+\cos (A)\sin (B)$$
$$\sin(2C)=2\sin (C)\cos (C)$$
$$\cos(2D)=2\cos^2(D)-1,$$we have$$\begin{align}\frac{\sin(5a)}{\sin(a)}&=\frac{\sin(4a+a)}{\sin(a)}\\&=\frac{\sin(4a)\cos(a)+\cos(4a)\sin(a)}{\sin(a)}\\&=\frac{2\sin(2a)\cos(2a)\cos(a)}{\sin(a)}+\cos(4a)\\&=\frac{2\cdot 2\sin(a)\cos(a)\cdot \cos(2a)\cos(a)}{\sin(a)}+\cos(4a)\\&=2\cdot 2\cos^2(a)\cos(2a)+\cos(4a)\\&=2(\cos(2a)+1)\cos(2a)+\cos(4a)\\&=2\cos^2(2a)+2\cos(2a)+\cos(4a)\\&=\cos(4a)+1+2\cos(2a)+\cos(4a)\\&=2\cos(4a)+2\cos(2a)+1\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

By using [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials), that is the same as proving that:

$$ 2 T_4(x) + 2 T_2(x) + 1 = U_4(x). \tag{1}$$

Both the LHS and the RHS are even polynomials with degree four. The leading term of $T_n$ is $2^{n-1} x^n$ and the leading term of $U_n$ is $2^n x^n$, so the leading terms match. Moreover, $T_n(0)=1$ and $U_n(0)=n+1$, so we just have to check that the coefficient of $x^2$ is the same, or that the value in $x=1$ is the same. Since $T_n(1)=1$ while $U_n(1)=n+1$, that is straightforward, too.

---

Another approach is the following one. Let $z=e^{i\theta}$. Then:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\frac{\sin(n\theta)}{\sin\theta}=\frac{z^n-\frac{1}{z^n}}{z-\frac{1}{z}}=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}z^{n-1-j}\frac{1}{z^j}\end{eqnarray*} $$
so:
$$\frac{\sin((2n+1)\theta)}{\sin\theta} = 1+2\cos(2\theta)+\ldots+2\cos(2n\theta).\tag{2}$$

---

Still another approach: multiply both sides of $(2)$ by $\sin\theta$ and compute the telescopic sum given by:
$$ 2\cos(2m\theta)\sin\theta = \sin((2m+1)\theta)-\sin((2m-1)\theta).\tag{3}$$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Product to sum formula$$\sin\left(\phi\right)\cos\left(\theta\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sin\left(\theta+\phi\right)-\sin\left(\theta-\phi\right)\right)
 $$ and your equation is equivalent to $$2\cos\left(2a\right)\sin\left(a\right)+2\cos\left(4a\right)\sin\left(a\right)+\sin\left(a\right)=\sin\left(5a\right).$$

Comment: Why the downvote? What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Using the identities $\color{blue}{\sin(x+y)=\sin x\cos y+\cos x\sin y}$ and  $\color{blue}{\sin(2x)=2\sin x\cos x}$ we get
\begin{align*}
\sin (5a)&=\sin (a)\cos(4a)+\cos (a)\sin (4a)\\
&=\sin(a)\cos(4a)+4\cos^2 (a)\sin (a)\cos(2a)\\
&=\sin(a)\cos(4a)+4[1-\sin^2 (a)]\sin (a)\cos(2a)\\
&=\sin(a)\cos(4a)+2\sin (a)\cos(2a)+2\sin(a)[1-2\sin^2(a)]\cos(2a)\\
&=\sin(a)\cos(4a)+2\sin (a)\cos(2a)+2\sin(a)\cos^2(2a)\\
&=\sin(a)\cos(4a)+2\sin (a)\cos(2a)+\sin(a)[\cos(4a)+1]\\
&=\sin(a)[2\cos(4a)+2\cos(2a)+1]
\end{align*}
Where also were used $\color{blue}{1-2\sin^2x=\cos(2x)=2\cos^2-1}$ and the Pythagorean identity $\color{blue}{\cos^2 x=1-\sin^2 x}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment**

The question is invalid unless $a$ is specified to be not a multiple of $π$.

**Method 1**

Seeing $\sin(a)$ and $\cos(4a)$ one immediately thinks of $\sin(5a) = \sin(a) \cos(4a) + \cos(a) \sin(4a)$, which transforms the equation to the equivalent $\cos(4a) + 2 \cos(2a) + 1 = \frac{ \cos(a) \sin(4a) } { \sin(a) }$. Again, we see so many terms of another identity $\sin(3a) = \sin(4a) \cos(-a) + \cos(4a) \sin(-a)$. I'm sure you can finish the rest in the same way.

**Method 2**

Use complex numbers and express $\sin(z) = \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$. Then it reduces the whole thing to just purely algebraic computation. This method only works better for ad-hoc identities that are not inductively constructed.

Answer (score 0):

A non standard approach:

The LHS is clearly a polynomial in $\cos^2(a)$, by the doubling identity. So is the RHS, by expanding $(\cos(a)+i\sin(a))^5$ and considering the imaginary part (even powers of $\cos$ and odd powers of $\sin$).

Then it suffices to show that the two sides coincide for three different values of $\cos(a)$.

$$a=\frac\pi4\to LHS(a)=-1=RHS(a),$$
$$a=\frac\pi3\to LHS(a)=-1=RHS(a),$$
$$a=\frac\pi2\to LHS(a)=1=RHS(a).$$

Answer (score -1):

Using the arc addition formula one gets

$$\sin{5a}=\cos{4a}\sin{a}+\sin{4a}\cos{a}$$

Now use $\sin{4a}=2\sin{2a}\cos{2a}=4\sin{a}\cos{a}\cos{2a}$

$${\sin{5a}\over \sin{a}}=\cos{4a}+4\cos^2{a}\cos{2a}$$

Now keep in mind that $\cos^2{a}={\cos{2a}+1\over 2}$ to get

$${\sin{5a}\over \sin{a}}=\cos{4a}+2\cos^2{2a}+2\cos{2a}$$

And finally use $2\cos^2{2a}=\cos{4a}+1$ to get to

$${\sin{5a}\over \sin{a}}=2\cos{4a}+2\cos{2a}+1$$